# How to add dataLayer object and Google Tag Manager container snippet from body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a few dynamic values which I get inside the body tag only. Now when I try to push those values using dataLayer object using 'script' tag and prepend it to the head section, it does not work.

Here is the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var JS = document.createElement('script');

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    var tagManagerSnippet = '(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({"gtm.start":\n' +
        'new Date().getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\n' +
        'j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!="dataLayer"?"&l="+l:"";j.async=false;j.src=\n' +
        '"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id="+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);\n' +
        '})(window,document,"script","dataLayer","GTM-XXXXXXXX");\n';
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    JS.text = tagManagerSnippet;
    head.prepend(JS);

    var code = 'dataLayer = [];\n' +
        'dataLayer.push({"eventLabel" : "Interested in Science"});\n' +
        'dataLayer.push({"eventLabel" : "Interested in IT"});\n';
    JS.text = code;
    head.prepend(JS);
</script>
```

I can see that the above code properly executes and append the JS in the head section. However, the Tag does not fire. And when I simply put the above code in the head section (not on the fly) it runs as expected.

Comment: When does that code get executed? I'm not entirely sure what you are doing, but perhaps the tags don't fire because you are overwriting the dataLayer array by declaring it after the GTM snippet. Can you remove the `var dataLayer = []` line?

Comment: Did you try declaring dataLayer before tag manager snippet?

Comment: @nyuen I did try removing the declaration of **dataLayer** but the result is still same. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Yes @ShivamAggarwal. Still nothing happens. Thanks for your time :-)